# Multiple calls to CryptHashData

Tags: winapi

I gather that this is creating an md5 hash, but confused about exactly what is being hashed.

```
char val1[4] = {...};
DWORD val2 = ...;

CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash)  // Creates hash object
CryptHashData(hHash, reinterpret_cast<const PBYTE>(val1), sizeof(val1), 0) // perform hash #1
CryptHashData(hHash, reinterpret_cast<const PBYTE>(val2), sizeof(val2), 0) // perform hash #2
```

How is hash #1 being combined with hash #2?

Is it performing an md5( md5(val1) + val2 )?  or an md5( val1 + val2 )?  Or something I'm not considering at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CryptHashData` adds your data to the hash object. If you call `CryptGetHashParam` later you are going to get the hash of val1+val2.

Comment: So if val2 is 0, for example, then I should be able to remove the second hash call without any effect to the final hash value?  that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: @LemonBeagle It is not the case because if you add a DWORD with the value 0 to the hash object the length of the data changed. A value of zero does not mean that no data is added to the hash object. It means that sizeof(DWORD) data with value 0 is added to the hash object.

Comment: Aha.. I was simply adding, not concatenating... thanks so much

Comment: I will vote you up when I get 15 rep... I wish I could now, this really helped, thanks